# Installing packages through bash scripting

Tags: bash, macos

I have never written any bash scripts at this point and my understanding of them is still pretty green. I was curious after reformatting my Mac if it is possible to write a script that does the majority of installs in an automated fashion?

For instance I use `homebrew` so maybe a portion of the script could verify if this is on the Mac and if not then initiate the install. Then it could proceed with the list of `brew install` & `brew cask installs`.

This is something that after realizing how much I had installed and had to remember and still am remembering to install I think would be pretty cool to make...I just don't know if a) it's possible with the macOS or how-to (I'll read up on the how-to). I'm not even too sure if bash-scripts would be the thing to use for something like this or not. Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on an RPM based system I would eventually list the packages installed, backup the list and then chain it in a yum install command.

For instance:

yum list installed
A
B
C

then to reinstall

yum install A B C -y

Extremely easy and straight forward.

I do believe you can do the same with brew:

brew list
brew install based on the list

I hope this helps

Comment: awesome! I was unaware of the `list` command. This will help out a lot :) thanks!